# Subsetting data based on dynamic column names

Tags: r

I have a dataset called DF. I wish to filter DF based on Column1, so I do:

```
DFb <- subset(DF, Column1 == "ABC")
```

Now, I wish for Column1 to be dynamically defined based on user input, so the user can filter based on any Column. Something like this:

```
Column_Name = 'Column3'  ## User defines this variable
DFb <- subset(DF, as.name(Column_Name) == "ABC")
```

However, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[[`-subsetting:

```
DFb <- DF[DF[[Column_Name]] == "ABC",]
```

This is not as elegant as `subset()`, but it works. `subset()` uses "non-standard evaluation", which is very convenient for interactive use, but makes things more complicated when you want to do this kind of second-order reference.

The main thing is the `[[`; you could use `subset(DF,DF[[Column_Name]]=="ABC")` instead, the results will be (almost) equivalent (`subset()` automatically drops values where the criterion evaluates to `NA` ...)

You can do this in the `dplyr` package, which allows more flexibility in avoiding non-standard evaluation, but it's still a bit roundabout (there may be a better way to do this: I'm not very experienced with `dplyr`).

```
library("dplyr")    ## for filter_()
library("lazyeval") ## for interp()
colname <- "speed"
filter_(cars,interp(~ var == 4, var = as.name(colname)))
```